# How I can setup Apache Unomi?

Tags: java, maven, apache-unomi

When I am setup Apache Unomi.
When I am running code using mvn clean install
I am getting an error.

```
INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  50.602 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-20T13:28:57+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.sebastian-daschner:jaxrs-analyzer-maven-plugin:0.17:analyze-jaxrs (default) on project cxs-privacy-extension-rest: Execution default of goal com.sebastian-daschner:jaxrs-analyzer-maven-plugin:0.17:analyze-jaxrs failed.: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :cxs-privacy-extension-rest
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get started with unomi is to use docker they provide. Then you will probably have problems with setting rules etc. then you can use [tracardi](https://github.com/atompie/tracardi) GUI to help you with umoni set-up.